# FFMPEG in android issue

Tags: android, ffmpeg, media-player, avi

I have successfully compiled the FFMPEG library to android using NDK.
(using Rock Player FFMPEG  implementation)http://www.rockplayer.com/download/rockplayer_ffmpeg_git_20100418.zip

I know that FFMPEG supports .avi, divX, mov ect. But I created a mediaplayer and tried to run them but I was not able to play them. I is this the right way to use the FFMPEG library. Can Any one Help.I am able to play defaut video, mp4, 3gp etc. Here is the code for mediaplayer

```
   public native String  stringFromJNI();
      static {
         System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
         System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg-test-jni");
             }
    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView  tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText( stringFromJNI() );


    System.gc();

    Log.d("Video FFmpeg ", "**");

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/simple.avi";

    Log.d("File path", filepath);

    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this); 

    VideoView video=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(video);
    video.setVideoPath(filepath);
    video.setMediaController(mc);
    mc.show();
    //video.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/Movies/Ishq-Hothon-Se.3gp");

    video.start();     
    View nextButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent i=new Intent(this,NextVideo.class);
   startActivity(i);

  }

  }
```